# Phonegap 3.5.0 requestFileSystem Working intermittently

Tags: android, cordova

I am using requestFileSystem on Phonegap 3.5.0 with Android device on USB debugging.

Part of the app uses the requestFileSystem (with Persistent storage) to save files and later load and read the files.

The call seems to be working intermittently, sometimes reading the files/directories as expected, other times it doesn't even get past the initial requestFileSystem call. Also the error callback handler never fires.

I've seen other issues of the requestFileSystem not working at all, but this is working half the time. I've done as many tests as I can think of to replicate, but the issue seems completely random.

Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You ever figure this out? Running into it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but have now placed the call to requestfilesystem into a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFSHtmlR, onFail);
});
```

and it seems to be working now.